# List of different generic types, dynamic casting

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have a following problem:

- I need to store generic objects with different type parameters, something like javish `Sth<A,?>`,
- "?" types are usually primitives, so not really expandable/changeable
- I need to execute some methods on each element of my list

  - different methods for different types, or at least different overloads of these methods

While I don't know how to store such types, let's assume `List<object>` for simplicity.

I could store the type in question somewhere (`List<KeyValuePair<Type,object>>`), getting it with `typeof()`, but then, how can I cast my object back to the required type?
Something like

```
foreach(var entry in myList)
{
    var obj = (Sth<A, entry.Key>) entry.Value;
    myMethod(obj); //This can have overloads for object, Sth<A,int>, Sth<A,string>,
                   // etc. Generally, I need a correct type of obj here.
}
```

Of course `myMethod<T>` is a generic library method with too many overloads to if-else it with `obj is Sth<A, uint>`...

I think I could create a new object based on `entry.Key` and then fill

Are such combinations with types even possible?

I believe, that the answer lies in proper creation of `myList`, but I don't know how to do it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Merry xmas :)

Comment: What does `myMethod` do?  At some point aren't you going to have to cast the object to something meaningful to use it?

Comment: Well, this `myMethod` is not in fact mine ;] The problem is that I don't know the sources and can't say which types are important.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using C# 4, you can use `dynamic` for this:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<A, object> entry in myList)
{
    dynamic value = entry.Value;
    myMethod(value);
}
```

The overload resolution will now be performed at execution time based on the execution-time type of `value`.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks for help (and sorry for late reply), this dynamic thingy is new to me. But it seems it's exactly what I was looking for.